# iOS - Determining the cause of a crash (from a crash report) in _WebTryThreadLock

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports

I have been trying to figure out what is causing one of the top crashes in my iOS application. It looks like there is some layout happening on a background thread which is causing it to crash. Is there any way to determine what I might be doing that is triggering this relayout? I assume from the stack that it is related to a UIWebView when my app is being brought back into the foreground.

Other stackoverflow threads on the topic seem to mention things like triggering a table reload on a background thread. As far as I can see all the webView delegate methods get called on the main thread. Is there some case where this is not true or are there some other methods which get called on a background thread and I'm just not aware?

Web Thread - Crashed.

```
0    WebCore _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 297
1    WebCore _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 288
2    WebCore WebThreadLock + 66
3    UIKit -[UIWebDocumentView(UIWebDocumentViewTextSelecting) selectionBaseWritingDirection] + 10
4    UIKit -[UITextField _currentTextAlignment] + 86
5    UIKit -[UITextField _showsClearButtonWhenNonEmpty:] + 58
6    UIKit -[UITextField _textRectForBounds:forEditing:] + 678
7    UIKit -[UITextField editingRectForBounds:] + 52
8    UIKit -[UITextField editRect] + 70
9    UIKit -[UITextField layoutSubviews] + 1320
10   UIKit -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 258
11   QuartzCore -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 214
12   QuartzCore CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 460
13   QuartzCore CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
14   QuartzCore CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 238
15   QuartzCore CA::Transaction::commit() + 316
16   QuartzCore CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 60
17   CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
18   CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 276
19   CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394
20   CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
21   WebCore RunWebThread(void*) + 444
22   libsystem_c.dylib pthread_start + 308
```

Main - Thread

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1    libsystem_c.dylib pthread_mutex_lock + 392
2    WebCore _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 336
3    WebCore WebThreadLock + 66
4    WebKit -[WebDatabasePauser applicationWillEnterForeground] + 16
5    CoreFoundation _CFXNotificationPost + 1426
6    Foundation -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
7    UIKit -[UIApplication _sendWillEnterForegroundCallbacks] + 154
8    UIKit -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 1094
9    UIKit -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1292
10   UIKit -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
11   UIKit _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6154
12   GraphicsServices _PurpleEventCallback + 590
13   CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
14   CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
15   CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun + 646
16   CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
17   CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
18   GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 74
19   UIKit UIApplicationMain + 1120
20   AppName main.m line 23
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are updating UI on the background thread, in your code add this line wherever you are updating your UI and you are fetching data on the background thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Update data here
});
```

As soon as you, rather code feels that data is there on device and it's time to update the UI corresponding to new data then try and bring back main thread in action.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. So my main problem is that I'm not sure where this update on the background thread is happening. As far as I can tell all the notifications are happening on the main thread. I have tried setting breakpoints and logging on every function related to the UIWebView. Is there some common callback with respect to webviews that happens on the background thread that I'm just missing?

Comment: Are you having this method? - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
} This is something that could tell you that webview has finished loading and now you can pass the control to main thread.

Comment: Or do this in your code and test if it works well - 

// Create and alloc UIWebView object, I called it as webViewObj
NSURL *webURLObj = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURLObj];
    
    [webViewObj loadRequest:request];
    
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
        [webViewObj release];
        
    });
    
});

Comment: @RenoJones: from my tests, `webViewDidFinishLoad:` and other UIWebView delegate methods are always called on the main thread.